# Does anyone know the function definition for kernel32!BaseAppXExtension

Tags: winapi, microsoft-metro, prototype

I am trying to figure out the signature for BaseAppXExtension used to create an appcontainer in win8 and above.
Has anyone figured out the parameters it takes?

Comment: Why do you need to access this API directly? If it is not documented as a public API, then it is private and not meant to be used directly.  Whatare you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time a dev has used an undocumented API in the Win32 subsystem!

Comment: That's... not really solid justification for doing so yourself. What exactly is this 'appcontainer' thing and why aren't you able to do it the documented way?

Comment: From what I can gather you create an appcontainer by using the `/APPCONTAINER` linker option, so it sounds like this is not something you can define at runtime; are you trying to define it at runtime?

Comment: andlabs, in reality, any Win32 App can be started within an AppContanier. Typical examples are Office (when opening in protected view), chrome and a lot of other applications. The trick is to pass additional parameters when creating the process. This is exactly what's done by the DCOM service when launching metro apps and a developer can do the same.